# If I have a local rpm in my ansible-playbook can I do yum install in one step?

Tags: redhat, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have downloaded a rpm in my ansible-playbook:

```
(djangoenv)~/P/c/apache-installer ❯❯❯ tree .
.
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── files
│   ├── apache2latest.tar
│   ├── httpd_final.conf
│   ├── httpd_temp.conf
│   └── sshpass-1.05-9.1.i686.rpm
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── hosts
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── README.md
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
├── templates
├── tests
│   ├── inventory
│   └── test.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml
```

My question is why can't I just install it using:

```
 - yum: name=files/sshpass-1.05-9.1.i686.rpm
```

? It complains that `files/sshpass-1.05-9.1.i686.rpm` is not found in the system. Now I am doing it in two steps:

```
 - copy: src=files/sshpass-1.05-9.1.i686.rpm dest=/tmp/sshpass-1.05-9.1.i686.rpm force=no
 - yum: name=/tmp/sshpass-1.05-9.1.i686.rpm state=present
```

Comment: AFAIK this it not supported out of the box. If you utterly need this, you can write action plugin `yum` as a wrapper of the module to accomplish this. You can start with [unarchive](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/unarchive.py) as an example (it can copy local file before processing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no simple way around coping the package to the remote host before installing. Ansible yum module expects a local file when you define a file in the name parameter.

IMHO it is not a good idea to keep packages inside the Ansible code base. Because they are binary and not exactly part of the actual Ansible code. It would be cleaner to setup a private repository and store those files there. That is the only way around coping a package in this situation I'm aware of.